# django form queryset multiple same field filter

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter my user field queryset based on 3 department id. I'm able to filter a single department but when I try to filter multiple times it's not working. Can anyone help me with this? My code is below:

form.py

```
class EditProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    prefix = 'edit_form'
    class Meta:
        model = Model_A
        fields = '__all__'
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EditProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = Employee.objects.filter(department__id=18).filter(department__id=19).filter(department__id=20)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current query is trying to find employees which have department id 18 *and* 19 *and* 20. If `department` is a foreign key, that is not possible.

You can use `Q()` objects to find employees which have department id 18 *or* 19 *or* 20.

```
Employee.objects.filter(Q(department=18)|Q(department=19)|Q(department=20))
```

However in your case, the simplest solution is to use `__in` to return employees where the department id is any one of 18, 19 or 20.

```
Employee.objects.filter(department__in=[18, 19, 20])
```

Comment: Thank you  very much, just what I'm looking for, will accept the answer in 11 minutes. thanks again!

Comment: Hi @Alasdair, I just realize, when I filter my queryset for some reason, when I save my form, its not saving, do you have any idea?

Comment: That sounds like a different issue. There isn't any code in your question that saves your form, so I can't help with that.